# Ionic with $http and it got triggered twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

```
$scope.login = function(email,password){
$http({
method: 'POST',
url: 'http://example.com/login',
headers: {
'owner': $rootScope.secret
},
data: {email:email, password:password }
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
console.log(response.data)
}, function errorCallback(response) {
console.log(response.data)
});
}
```

But in my network tab I'm seeing 2 request, one is by ionic :

[image]

The second one is my POST request, I wonder why there's one OPTION method up there.

Comment: That is the pre-flight OPTIONS request for CORS. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Preflight_example

Comment: @georgeawg is this a mistake? how should I avoid this?

Comment: It is normal and nothing to be avoided. The ionic framework makes the OPTIONS request in order to get permission to do Cross Origin Resource Requests. It is a natural part of your browsers web security system.

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS issue.
You can do these things:

- Start your chrome with `--disable-web-security`.
- Make a proxy server to forward calls.
- Add this header to your call:

  ```
  {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
  ```

Comment: is this only in chrome? should I take care of this in production later?

Comment: For production I would highly recommend just making a simple proxy server.

Comment: proxy server for restful? how does that solve the cors?